# How to pause and unpause a turtle program - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So i have an algorithm that can find the best path to exit a maze. However the problem is i am unable to implement a keypress button to pause and to unpause the algorithm using the spacebar as the keypress. For example i expect the algorithm to pause(not exit the window) when i hit the spacebar and when i hit the spacebar again it should continue running. It should work like a toggle switch basically.


The codes are as follows:

```
# Import libraries
import turtle
import sys
import numpy as np
import os
from collections import deque

# Configure some basic settings for the map
bs = turtle.Screen()                                       # Define the turtle screen
bs.bgcolor("black")                                        # Set the background colour
bs.setup(width=0.9, height=0.9)                            # Setup the dimensions of the working window 
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
in_motion = False

def stopMovement():
    global in_motion
    if in_motion == True:
        in_motion == False
    else:
        in_motion == True

while True:
    if not in_motion:
        # Setting up classes
        turtle.title("Breadth first search algorithm ; steps taken: 0")
        title = title()
        building = Building()
        road = Road()
        start = Start()
        end = End()
        searcher = Searcher()
        route = Route()
        sprite = sprite()

        # Setting up lists
        walls = []
        path = []   
        routeCoords = []
        visited = set()
        frontier = deque()
        solution = {} 

        # Activation
        setupMaze(mazeSet)
        search(start_x, start_y)
        correctRoute(end_x, end_y)
        sprite.moveSprite(end_x, end_y)
    else:
        bs.update()

bs.listen()
bs.onkeypress(stopMovement, 'space')
```

The if not in_motion part basically runs the functions for the algorithm. I have already tried implementing the switch to pause and unpause but it still does not seem to work. Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem?  e.g. what do you expect this code to do, what does it do wrong, do you get any errors, etc.  As it is there is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @0x5453 The problem is that when i press the spacebar, the algorithm does not pause and instead continues running. I expect it to pause when i press on the spacebar and when i press on the spacebar again it should continue running so basically like a loop. I didnt get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

```
def stopMovement():
    global in_motion
    if in_motion == True:
        in_motion == False
    else:
        in_motion == True
```

should be

```
def stopMovement():
    global in_motion
    if in_motion == True:
        in_motion = False # here
    else:
        in_motion = True # and here
```

Two equal signs too much and such a big effect :)

Comment: @StackAsker7 Does it restart?

Comment: @ Just learned it   Nope it did not. The algorithm just continues running.

Comment: @ Just learned it If im not wrong it should be something to do with bs.update()?

Comment: @StackAsker7 Which part of your code does the updating? This part should be in a `if not in_motion` condition.

Comment: @ Just learned it its in the while True loop below else:, however i don't even know if i should be using bs.update().

Answer (score 0):

Not having runnable code to debug, I'm going to suggest that in addition to the `=` vs. `==` typos that @Justlearnedit points out, I believe that your `while True:` is keeping the event handler from seeing the keyboard input as infinite loops have no place in an event-driven world.  We should use timed events instead and I would reformulate your code something like:

```
# Import libraries
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
# ...

# Configure some basic settings for the map
screen = Screen()  # Define the turtle screen
screen.bgcolor('black')  # Set the background colour
screen.setup(width=0.9, height=0.9)  # Setup the dimensions of the working window

# ...

in_motion = False

def flipMovement():
    global in_motion

    in_motion = not in_motion

def running():
    if not in_motion:
        screen.update()
    else:
        screen.title("Breadth first search algorithm ; steps taken: 0")

        # Set up classes
        title = title()
        building = Building()
        road = Road()
        start = Start()
        end = End()
        searcher = Searcher()
        route = Route()
        sprite = sprite()

        # Set up lists
        walls = []
        path = []
        routeCoords = []
        visited = set()
        frontier = deque()
        solution = {}

        # Activation
        setupMaze(mazeSet)
        search(start_x, start_y)
        correctRoute(end_x, end_y)
        sprite.moveSprite(end_x, end_y)

    screen.ontimer(running)

screen.onkeypress(flipMovement, 'space')
screen.listen()

running()
```